# How to edit only by click EditButton

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

[React admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) - A frontend Framework for building data-driven applications running in the browser on top of REST/GraphQL APIs, using ES6, React and Material Design. Open sourced and maintained by marmelab.

Clicking on any part of the row in PostList will open the editing form, how to make it possible to edit only by click the EditButton.

I make example for demonstration this behaviour [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-s34jqn?file=/src/App.tsx)

posts.tsx

```
export const PostList = () => (
  <List>
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="id" />
      <ReferenceField source="userId" reference="users">
        <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>

      <TextField source="title" />
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

App.tsx

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} />
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
  </Admin>
);
```

if i comment *edit={PostList}* edit button do not work

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} /*edit={PostEdit}*/ />
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
  </Admin>
);
```

I want edit post only by  click Edit Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `rowClick="edit"` from datagrid

```
export const PostList = () => (
  <List>
    <Datagrid> // remove rowClick="edit"
      <TextField source="id" />
      <ReferenceField source="userId" reference="users">
        <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>

      <TextField source="title" />
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```